# Open Excel 2010 Workbook in IIS7 cause "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Tags: c#, excel, iis-7

I write this code for open an excel file:

```
    private readonly object _missing = Type.Missing;

    private IEnumerable<CellModel> GetUsedCells(string fileName)
    {
        SetNewCurrentCulture();//set "en-US" culture

        var application = new Application();
        var workbooks = application.Workbooks;
        Workbook workbook = null;

        try
        {
            workbook = workbooks
                .Open(fileName,
                      0, false, _missing, "", "",
                      true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, _missing, false, false,
                      _missing, false, false, XlCorruptLoad.xlNormalLoad
                );
        }
        finally
        {
            //realocate memory

            if(workbook != null)
            {
                ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                workbook = null;
            }

            workbooks.Close();
            ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            workbooks = null;

            application.Quit();
            ReleaseComObject(application);
            application = null;

            GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

            ResetCurrentCulture();//reset old culture
        }
    }
```

and in Open method this error has occured : "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

notes:

- I use vs2012 and Target Framework of my project is 4 and version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is 14.0.0.0
- Server info: Windows Server 2008 32-bit, IIS7, Excel 2010
- I create Desktop folder in "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile" and set permission to "Network Services" and "Users"
- Change Permissions in DCOM Config in "Microsoft Excel Application" and select "Interactive User"
- Set permission to "Network Services" and "Users" for "C:\Windows\Temp"

I'm very confused. help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Interop is NOT supported in sever-scenarios by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).**

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop/installing Excel on the server:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write all MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Comment: I need to work with xls, xlsx and even csv. In my application users upload their excel files (xls, xlsx and csv) and I should read data. So is there any solution for me except Interop?

Comment: @OmidRH yes, there several solutions - for XLSX and CSV there are free ones, for XLS there AFAIK only commercial ones... for all this I already provided links in my answer above...

Comment: I'm stuck with interop (I have a boss... so things like that still happen)
any thoughts? `xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);` throws me the feared COMException

Comment: @SparK send your boss the first link from my answer - perhaps he then understands that Interop is NOT the way to go...

Comment: @Yahia Found a way to make it open... the workbook.Open method has a lot of optional parameters that specify the default behaviour for alert messages and confirmation dialogs that Excel may throw to the user while opening. Once I set the parameters I needed using C#'s `method(parameter: value);` syntax, the error stopped.
I also set `CorruptLoad: XlCorruptLoad.XlRepairFile` and `xlApp.Quit(false)` so it doesn't save changes.